# Pico W OLED display garbled

Tags: pi-pico-w

I trying to get an OLED display working with a Pico W:

micropython build: MicroPython v1.20.0-117-ged7a3b11d on 2023-05-24;

ssd1306 library: micropython-ssd1306 v .3

When I run:

```
from machine import Pin, I2C
from ssd1306 import SSD1306_I2C

sda=machine.Pin(16)
scl=machine.Pin(17)
i2c=machine.I2C(0,sda=sda, scl=scl, freq=200000)

print('Scan i2c bus...')
devices = i2c.scan()

oled = SSD1306_I2C(128, 64, i2c)

oled.text("WELCOME!", 0, 0)
oled.show()

for device in devices:
    print("Decimal address: ",device," | Hexa address: ",hex(device))
```

I get a snow screen:
[image: snowscreen]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that is a ssd1306 display?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and realized my OLED was using the SH1106 controller.  Found this library which seems to be working nicely so far: https://github.com/robert-hh/SH1106

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).